# AWS S3 images are not rendering React Express app

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

My stack:

- React
- Express with AWS SDK
- Deployed on fly.io

I am getting:

```
Refused to load the image 'https://say-yes-events.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/event-images/0342Andrei_profile.jpg' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".
```

error in console while trying to render an image from AWS S3.

I've tried fixing the issue by:

- Adding

  ```html
  <meta
    http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="img-src 'self' data: https://say-yes-events.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/ 'unsafe-inline';"
  />
  ```

  tag to `index.html` in `/public`
- Providing CORS JSON config on my AWS S3

  ```json
  [
      {
          "AllowedHeaders": [
              "*"
          ],
          "AllowedMethods": [
              "GET"
          ],
          "AllowedOrigins": [
              "*"
          ],
          "ExposeHeaders": []
      }
  ]
  ```
- Making sure that S3 public access is allowed

Comment: The issue was that I used "helmet" as middleware in my express.js server which was changing http headers to strict policies to protect from possible vulnerabilities like XSS.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! If you think your solution will help future readers, please add it as an Answer. However, if it was caused by something that is unlikely to be useful for future readers, feel free to delete your Question.